# How do I install .NET on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, installation, .net

I have a Windows Server 2003 server that I need to have at least .NET 2.x installed on.

Is there somewhere within the OS where I can tell it to download it from Microsoft?

**or**

Do I **have** to download the runtime from Microsoft manually and then install it?
(I know I can do it this way, but is there another way?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the [.NET Framework 2.0 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en) and [.NET Framework 3.5 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en) from Microsoft downloads and run them manually on the server. If you have more than one server, you should have them setup to recieve updates from a central area much like Zypher said.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: .net 2 link is broken, also I could not find the redistributable for 32bit at all, only for 64bit. .net 3.5 seems to include prior versions, incl. 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can either push it via WSUS, or you are going to need to download it from MS (preferable to a central software share so you only have to download once) and push it via GPO/SCCM/some other install solution. or manually install it.

Comment: I'm dealing with a naked Win2K3 box. No other infrastructure other than network access through a firewall.

Comment: @CodeSlave: Then yes you do HAVE to download the install. .Net 1.1 is part of 2k3 (starting sp1 i believe) any others you have to go and download the installer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) from Microsoft. That's easy and very efficient.

Comment: Actually, the Web Platform Installer is pretty good. It does bring down alot of web related items and combines them into a nice neat package.

Answer (score 0):

Run Windows Update and Select the features you want to install.

Comment: I don't see an option to do that, and it's not showing up in my Add or Remove Programs (so I presume that it's not installed)